# How to set date format of @CreatedDate в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an entity:

```
@Data
@EntityListeners(value = AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

And such config of JpaAuditing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class EntityListenerConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.ofNullable("system");
    }
}
```

And get this type record in my DB:

```
"createdDate": "2021-06-22T19:42:37.805621"
```

How can I set the date format such set in my @JsonFormat? I don't know but it doesn't work

Comment: Why would JSON formatting help for storing something in the database? That will only work for showing it in JSON.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right, but when I do get request in postman I see that type of record, Actually I don't care how it stores a record in DB, I need to get it back from DB with suth type of format to show it on the frontend.

Comment: Use the annotations for the tools you are using. This has nothing to do with the DB but more on how to format dates in your result for the web. Now you included nothing related to that (controllers, views etc.).